# AzureDevOps ServiceNow - Getting error "Operation against file 'change_request' was aborted by Business Rule" while updating change request

Tags: azure-devops, task, servicenow, change-management

I'm getting an error when trying to update the ticket to close state after a successful release trigger.

Error message:

```
Operation against file 'change_request' was aborted by 
Business Rule 'Transform synchronously^0e85c8badb33a3047137ab8b4b96195a'. 
Business Rule Stack:Transform synchronously,State model - Can change state?
```

Why is the update failing, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For Normal change request type, ServiceNow Change management follows [this](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/london-it-service-management/page/product/change-management/concept/c_ChangeStateModel.html) state model (by default), which means you can change state to ‘**Closed’** from  ‘**Review’** state.  Please check the state of change request for which update state is failing. You cannot update state directly from say **'Implement'** to **'Closed'** for default state model.